# Script that checks the GPO Values

Tags: powershell, gpo

I am trying to do a Powershell script in a Windows Server 2019. The script must check some values of the gpo eg:"Enforce password history is set to 24 or more"

if the checking is OK leave it like that and if not, change it to the value that must be.

I have tried many ways but i cannot do it. Any idea???

Comment: What have you tried. Show us the code you have written (an MRE), tell what happens, and tell what should happen. https://stackoverflow.com/help